# Update dynamic content automatically - Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to make a chat app in python flask and need help automatically updating the messages a user recieves wihout having to reload the page.

Here is the Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, make_response


app = Flask(__name__)

messages = []



@app.route('/log-in', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def log_in():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form['username']

    resp = make_response(redirect(url_for('index')))

    resp.set_cookie('username', username)

    return resp

  return render_template('log_in.html')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    username = request.cookies.get('username')
    if username is None:
        return redirect(url_for('log_in'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.form['message']
        messages.append({'message': message, 'username': username})
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', messages=messages, username=username)



if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=81)
```

Here is the Jinja:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Chat App - welcome {{ username }}</h1>
    <div id="chat">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <p><strong>{{ message.username }}:</strong> {{ message.message }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message" required>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
   
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using an ajax but could not figure that out.

Comment: If you're looking at making a Chat app look at [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: Also [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use api and ajax in js to achive in basics.

Api will return jsonified data and ajax will call it and variable = await function(object);

Function can be async function (if used with await) and you can put your text to your html object to show without refreshing the page.

Here a small example with no async function:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Quote Generator</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getRandomQuote() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/get_quote",
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#quote").text(data.quote);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>
    <button onclick="getRandomQuote()">Get Random Quote</button>
    <p id="quote">Click the button to get a random quote.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

flask part :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

quotes = [
    "Flask is a micro web framework for Python.",
    "AJAX allows you to update parts of a web page without a full page reload.",
    "This is a sample quote.",
]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/get_quote', methods=['GET'])
def get_quote():
    random_quote = random.choice(quotes)
    return jsonify({"quote": random_quote})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

At the success: function(data) {} part u can add ur modifications